# Is it possible to include maplines in highcharter maps?

Tags: r, highcharts

I'd like to use one set of borderColor and width values for counties and another set for state lines in highcharter as done [in this jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/us-counties/).

```
series: [{
            mapData: countiesMap,
            data: data,
            joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
            name: 'Unemployment rate',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#bada55'
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'mapline',
            name: 'State borders',
            data: [lines[0]],
            color: 'white'
        }, {
            type: 'mapline',
            name: 'Separator',
            data: [lines[1]],
            color: 'gray'
        }]
```

However, I don't understand the data structure and I don't see how the highcharter api allows this to be done. Is this kind of map possible? My first instinct was to add a polygon layer without fill for state borders but this doesn't seem to be the approach to use in highmaps/highcharts.

The effect I'm after is shown [here](http://images.flatworldknowledge.com/campbell/campbell-fig06_019.jpg). Bold state borders with lighter county borders. Sorry, not enough reputation to embed images.

Comment: Hi michael, have you a link with a similar example. Due every map series have fix their attributes maybe one approach to test is add a county one by one with their specifics colors/width etc

Comment: I edited my question above w/ the jsfilddle link. Perhaps it is a bit more clear now. I'm just a few days in to using your package and am very impressed. Thank you for writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is same answer by Roco, but is using highcharter.

live:
http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/is-it-possible-to-include-maplines-in-highcharter-maps

code:

```
library("highcharter")
library("viridisLite")
library("dplyr")

data(unemployment)
data(uscountygeojson)
data(usgeojson)
dclass <- data_frame(from = seq(0, 10, by = 2),
                     to = c(seq(2, 10, by = 2), 50),
                     color = substring(viridis(length(from), option = "C"), 0, 7))
dclass <- list.parse3(dclass)
highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(uscountygeojson, unemployment, value = "value", joinBy = "code",
                    lineWidth = 0.5, color = hex_to_rgba("#000000", 0.75)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = uscountygeojson, type = "mapline",
                lineWidth = 2, color = hex_to_rgba("#000000", 0.75)) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = dclass)
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks for use the package!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the width of the borders, you would normally do that with via`borderWidth` property, like you already do for the county lines.

Your state lines are of different type, they belong to the `mapline` type. For this type, the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#series%3Cmapline%3E.lineWidth) specifies that you need to use **`lineWidth`** rather than `borderWidth`. This is what you need to change:

```
{
  type: 'mapline',
  name: 'State borders',
  data: [lines[0]],
  color: 'black',
  lineWidth: 4
}
```

This is an example of how I changed your initial JSFiddle to make the state lines much thicker than the county lines:
[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zfryz8j6/)

[image]