# Drawing arbitrary lines on a highchart map in R (library highcharter)

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am drawing a highcharts map using the highcharter package in R. I added already some points (cities) and want to link them by drawing an additionnal beeline using the world map-coordinates.

I already managed to draw the beelines by first drawing the map, then hovering over the cities which shows me the plot-coordinates, and then redrawing the plot using the aforementioned plot-coordinates. (Watch out: I used the PLOT-coordinates and my goal is to use directly the WORLD MAP-coordinates.)
If you only have 1 or two cities, it's not a big deal. But if you have like 100 cities/points, it's annoying. I guess the answer will be something like here: [Is it possible to include maplines in highcharter maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381592/is-it-possible-to-include-maplines-in-highcharter-maps).

Thank you!

Here my code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)    

# cities with world coordinates
ca_cities <- data.frame(
  name = c("San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco"),
  lat = c(32.715736, 34.052235, 37.773972), # world-map-coordinates
  lon = c(-117.161087, -118.243683, -122.431297) # world-map-coordinates
)

# path which I create AFTER the first drawing of the map as I get the 
# plot-coordinates when I hover over the cities.
path <- "M669.63,-4963.70,4577.18,-709.5,5664.42,791.88"
# The goal: the path variable above should be defined using the WORLD-
# coordinates in ca_cities and not using the PLOT-coordinates.

# information for drawing the beeline
ca_lines <- data.frame(
  name = "line",
  path = path, 
  lineWidth = 2
)

# construct the map
map <- hcmap("countries/us/us-ca-all", showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = ca_cities, type = "mappoint", name = "Cities") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = ca_lines, type = "mapline", name = "Beeline", color = "blue") 
map
```

[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tD2G.png)

Answer (score 1):

After several hours, I found an answer to my problem. There are maybe easier ways, but I'm going to post my version using the rgdal-package.
The idea is to convert first the world map-coordinates to the specific map's coordinate system (ESRI) and then back-transform all adjustments from highcharts:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)    
library(rgdal) # you also need rgdal

# cities with world coordinates
ca_cities <- data.frame(
  name = c("San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco"),
  lat = c(32.715736, 34.052235, 37.773972), 
  lon = c(-117.161087, -118.243683, -122.431297) 
)

# pre-construct the map
map <- hcmap("countries/us/us-ca-all", showInLegend = FALSE) 

# extract the transformation-info
trafo <- map$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$mapData$`hc-transform`$default

# convert to coordinates
ca_cities2 <- ca_cities %>% select("lat", "lon")
coordinates(ca_cities2) <- c("lon", "lat")

# convert world geosystem WGS 84 into transformed crs
proj4string(ca_cities2) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS 84
ca_cities3 <- spTransform(ca_cities2, CRS(trafo$crs)) # 

# re-transform coordinates according to the additionnal highcharts-parameters
image_coords_x <- (ca_cities3$lon - trafo$xoffset) * trafo$scale * trafo$jsonres + trafo$jsonmarginX
image_coords_y <- -((ca_cities3$lat - trafo$yoffset) * trafo$scale * trafo$jsonres + trafo$jsonmarginY)

# construct the path
path <- paste("M",
              paste0(paste(image_coords_x, ",", sep = ""), 
              image_coords_y, collapse = ","), 
              sep = "")

# information for drawing the beeline
ca_lines <- data.frame(
  name = "line",
  path = path, 
  lineWidth = 2
)

# add series
map <- map %>%
  hc_add_series(data = ca_cities, type = "mappoint", name = "Cities") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = ca_lines, type = "mapline", name = "Beeline", color = "blue") 

map
```