# What type of data do I need for maplines in R highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to add a mapline object to a highcharter graph (ideally using hcmap as a base)--in my case, so county borders can look different than state borders.

I've seen the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381592/is-it-possible-to-include-maplines-in-highcharter-maps), but it doesn't work for me--indeed, running the answer's example code fails to create different lines for states and counties. Meanwhile, the more complex code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419855/drawing-arbitrary-lines-on-a-highchart-map-in-r-library-highcharter) *does* work, but I'm not sure what it's doing under the hood, or how I could use its method to create a mapline object of state boundaries. What kind of data do I need to add a working "mapline" series? Does anyone know a good source for one for state boundaries?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You ask specifically where to get/how to create a data path for changing these shapes?

Comment: I basically want to do what's being done in my first link--draw map lines for one map over map lines for another map (e.g., draw state boundaries more bold than county lines). Any ways to do so would be appreciated, since nothing I've seen seems to work.